# Getting index number of first word of row obtained from paragraph in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to obtain a column that will contain the index number of first word from the referenced column cell by cell.

I am able to get the length of word in a text, for upper cell value in have used `ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate` but it does not work for me.

```
Public Function StartIndex(ByVal strText As String) As Long

    Application.Volatile
    Length = UBound(Split(strText, " ")) + 1
    StartIndex = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate + Length

End Function
```

look below, consider I'm having **col1** by default and want **startIndex** through VBA;

```
      Col1                           |   startIndex        
VBA Index Printer Friendly version   |         1            
 Adobe Acrobat version               |         6          
A UDF can remain in a code module    |         9
```

as shown above consider the table have 3 rows and two columns,the index number of word **"VBA"**in col1 row1 is 1 similarly word **"is"** next to word **"VBA"** have an index of 2, and so on .. Consider the rows are a combination of a paragraph and so when we reach Col1 row2 the index of word **"Adobe"** should be 6 as shown in table

Actually startIndex column shows the index number of the first word from the paragraph which is divided in rows

Comment: Sorry, but what you are trying to achieve is not clear. You said *obtain a column that will contain the index number of first word from the referenced column cell by cell* but your example shows just 2 columns. Why first row returns 1? Why second one returns 6? Why third one returns 9? Please, be more specific.

Comment: Please look at the explanation now

Comment: I recommend to use formulas instead of VBA. They should calculate faster than VBA and they will automatically re-calculate if the data changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your original Function a litte bit, to be able to handle ranges:

```
Public Function StartIndex(ByVal vRNG As Range) As Long
Application.Volatile
Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In vRNG
    StartIndex = UBound(Split(rng.Value, " ")) + 1 + StartIndex
Next rng

End Function
```

Then, you can apply it like this:

```
=StartIndex($A$1:A1)+1
```

But to make it work you need to apply it from row 2....

[image]

Another option would be to input in B1 just a 1 (because it always going to be 1) and then in B2, same formula:

`=StartIndex($A$1:A1)+1`

And it would work:

[image]

Comment: In each line this calculates the amount of words again and again for all previosly rows. This means it gets slower and slower with each line you add. You should really us the previous cell and just add up the amount of words in the current row. This would be much faster.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, You are right. I did not think about how much data OP got. Also, I upvoted your answer because I think it's much better. I love VBA but I prefer to get a solution using normal formulas if possible.

Answer (score 2):

No need for VBA just use a formula to count the words:

Then add the amount of words to the previous amount of words (from the row above).

[image]

- Write `1` into B1 (it is always 1)
- Use the following formula in B2:

  ```
  =B1+LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",""))+1
  ```
- Copy the formula from B2 to B3

Comment: thank you so much, there was just a req of VBA, else your code is super awesome

Comment: @andro Note that formulas are often calculating faster than VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this slightly differently and pass the range instead.

```
Public Function StartIndex(ByVal textCell As Range) As Long

    Dim text As String
    text = textCell.Value

    Dim result As Long

    result = (UBound(Split(text, " ")) + 1)

    If textCell.Row > 1 Then
        result = result - (UBound(Split(textCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value, " ")) + 1)
    End If

    StartIndex = result

End Function
```

example use:

```
=StartIndex(A1)
```

or in VBA:

```
Dim index As Long
index = StartIndex(Range("A1"))
```

Comment: I would love to go with your approach but its showing some different result other than expected, can you correct it? the index position are not proper

Comment: I'd go with @Pᴇʜ answer anyway, it's far better - no need to re-invent the wheel and use VBA when it's not needed.